# Does Google analytics count as new users if users not revisit within 24hours on IOS14?

Tags: google, google-analytics, cookie, safari, ios

With regards to first party cookies, does Google analytics count as new users if the users not revisit on the website within 24 hours as a first party cookie is deleted within 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

If GA is looking for a cookie to track the user, and the cookie expires before the users visits your site (24 hours per your question), then we can expect GA to treat them as a new user.

However, it's only `_gid` that expires after 24 hours; `_ga` does not, it expires after two years. If a _ga cookie is not present, new Client ID for the new user (aka "New Users" in your GA reports).

[image]

---

### iOS 14 tracking changes

As far as I know, in iOS 14 Safari blocks all third-party cookies. I don't know of anything about first party cookies. There is added transparency and privacy reporting in Safari, what is tracking you is more visible. So if a user sees your cookie in their report (and doesn't want it) they can delete it.

**As long as you don't have an app** (so you're just a website) you only need to worry about changes in the Safari browser.

So *really* it's just Intelligent Tracking Prevention (or ITP) which has been updated and Apple's new Privacy Reports.

There are not any workarounds to [ITP related challenges](https://www.theverge.com/2020/3/24/21192830/apple-safari-intelligent-tracking-privacy-full-third-party-cookie-blocking) at the moment. So for now, the best you can do is monitor your data and see if/how the iOS 14 updates are affecting you and then go from there.